# 3D Geometry Package for Python

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, shapely

I am trying to find a good 3D geometry library for Python that has similar operations and functionality to Shapely.

http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

Shapely is great, and has exactly what I need, especially around the creation and manipulation of Linestring objects. Unfortunately, it only supports operations on 2D objects, even though 3D points can be created.

Does anybody know of any a similar module that operates in full 3D? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at Pymesh:

http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Its a new CSG wrapper for basic 3d geometry applications.

Is that the type of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at d3g package in PyPI.

Visit https://pypi.org/project/d3g

```py
pip install d3g
```