# How to change OCR from PyTesseract to AzureFormRecognizer

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, azure-form-recognizer

I am currently experimenting with a code I found on GitHub to extract highlighted text from scanned text using OCR. I wanted to try changing the OCRs used. Currently, the code uses PyTesseract. I wanted to try to use AzureFormRecognizer. I am a beginner with OCR softwares and this is my first time using AzureFormRecognizer. I have tried to change PyTesseract to AzureFormRecognizer straight up, but it hasn't worked at all. Please help me with this problem.

Sorry for the very long code. And thank you for your time and consideration.

Code:

```
import pprint
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
import re
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'PATH/TO/PYTESSERACT'

Rectangle = namedtuple('Rectangle', ['xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax'])
# It represents information about a word recognized by an OCR
# Word = namedtuple('Word', ['level', 'page_num',
#                   'block_num', 'par_num', 'line_num', 'word_num', 'top', 'left', 'width', 'height', 'conf', 'text'])

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152904/calculate-overlapped-area-between-two-rectangles


class Levels:
    PAGE = 1
    BLOCK = 2
    PARAGRAPH = 3
    LINE = 4
    WORD = 5


def intersect_area(a, b):
    """Calcluate intersection area between two rectangles. Each rectangle has xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax fields."""
    dx = min(a.xmax, b.xmax) - max(a.xmin, b.xmin)
    dy = min(a.ymax, b.ymax) - max(a.ymin, b.ymin)

    return float(dx*dy) if (dx >= 0) and (dy >= 0) else 0.


def normalize_images(images):
    """Convert all images into 3-dimensional images via cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR."""
    return [cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            if image.ndim == 2 else image for image in images]


def threshold_image(img_src):
    """Grayscale image and apply Otsu's threshold"""
    # Grayscale
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Binarisation and Otsu's threshold
    _, img_thresh = cv2.threshold(
        img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    return img_thresh, img_gray


def mask_image(img_src, lower, upper):
    """Convert image from RGB to HSV and create a mask for given lower and upper boundaries."""
    # RGB to HSV color space conversion
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv_lower = np.array(lower, np.uint8)  # Lower HSV value
    hsv_upper = np.array(upper, np.uint8)  # Upper HSV value

    # Color segmentation with lower and upper threshold ranges to obtain a binary image
    img_mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)

    return img_mask, img_hsv

def apply_mask(img_src, img_mask):
    """Apply bitwise conjunction of source image and image mask."""

    img_result = cv2.bitwise_and(img_src, img_src, mask=img_mask)

    return img_result


def denoise_image(img_src):
    """Denoise image with a morphological transformation."""

    # Morphological transformations to remove small noise
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
    img_denoise = cv2.morphologyEx(
        img_src, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

    # img_contour = img_denoise.copy()

    #This will remove all the highlights and replace it with white, i.e., unhighlighted text
    # # Find highligted contour and fill them with white color    
    # contours, hierarchy, = cv2.findContours(
    #     img_denoise, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # # contours, hierarchy, = cv2.findContours(
    # #     img_mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # for idx, c in enumerate(contours):
    #     # if(hierarchy[0][idx][3] != -1):  # Discard contours that are holes
    #     #     continue
    #     cv2.drawContours(img_contour, contours, idx,
    #                      (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED, 8, hierarchy)

    return img_denoise #, contours, hierarchy, img_contour

def draw_word_boundings(img_src, data_ocr, highlighted_words=False):
    """Draw word bounding boxes"""

    # Convert source image to RGB if it's grayscaled
    img_result = cv2.cvtColor(img_src, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) if img_src.ndim == 2 else img_src.copy()

    # Iterate through all words
    for i in range(len(data_ocr['text'])):
        # Skip for all non-word elements
        if data_ocr['level'][i] != Levels.WORD:
            continue
        if highlighted_words and not data_ocr['highlighted'][i]:
            continue
        # Get bounding box position and size of word
        (x, y, w, h) = (data_ocr['left'][i], data_ocr['top']
                        [i], data_ocr['width'][i], data_ocr['height'][i])
        # Draw bounding box in red                
        cv2.rectangle(img_result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    return img_result


def draw_contour_boundings(img_src, img_mask, threshold_area=400):
    """Draw contour bounding and contour bounding box"""
    # Contour detection
    contours, hierarchy, = cv2.findContours(
        img_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Create two copies of source image
    img_contour = img_src.copy()
    img_box = img_src.copy()

    for idx, c in enumerate(contours):
        # Skip small contours because its probably noise
        if  cv2.contourArea(c) < threshold_area:
            continue

        # Draw contour in red
        cv2.drawContours(img_contour, contours, idx, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4, hierarchy)

        # Get bounding box position and size of contour
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        # Draw bounding box in blue
        cv2.rectangle(img_box, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA, 0)

    return img_contour, img_box

def draw_contour_rectangles(img_contour, img_result, rect_width=10, rect_height=10, threshold_percentage=25):
    """Draw small rectangles within the contour if the respective rectangle area exceeds the defined threshold percentage."""

    # threshold for rectangle area
    threshold = (rect_width * rect_height * threshold_percentage) / 100
    contours, hierarchy, = cv2.findContours(
        img_contour, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for idx, c in enumerate(contours):
        xmin, ymin, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        xmax = xmin + w
        ymax = ymin + h

        # Scan the image with in bounding boxes
        for x in range(xmin, xmax, rect_width):
            for y in range(ymin, ymax, rect_height):
                rect_roi = Rectangle(x, y, x+rect_width, y+rect_height)
                img_roi = img_contour[y:y+rect_height, x:x+rect_width]

                # count white pixels within region of interest
                count = cv2.countNonZero(img_roi)

                if count > threshold:
                    cv2.rectangle(img_result, (rect_roi.xmin, rect_roi.ymin),
                                  (rect_roi.xmax, rect_roi.ymax),
                                  (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA, 0)

    return img_result



def find_highlighted_words(img_mask, data_ocr, threshold_percentage=25):
    """Find highlighted words by calculating how much of the words area contains white pixels compared to balack pixels."""

    # Initiliaze new column for highlight indicator
    data_ocr['highlighted'] = [False] * len(data_ocr['text'])

    for i in range(len(data_ocr['text'])):
        # Get bounding box position and size of word
        (x, y, w, h) = (data_ocr['left'][i], data_ocr['top']
                        [i], data_ocr['width'][i], data_ocr['height'][i])
        # Calculate threshold number of pixels for the area of the bounding box
        rect_threshold = (w * h * threshold_percentage) / 100
        # Select region of interest from image mask
        img_roi = img_mask[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # Count white pixels in ROI
        count = cv2.countNonZero(img_roi)
        # Set word as highlighted if its white pixels exceeds the threshold value
        if count > rect_threshold:
            data_ocr['highlighted'][i] = True

    return data_ocr


def mark_highlighted_words(img_result, data_ocr):
    # draw rectangles for words
    for i in range(len(data_ocr['text'])):
        if data_ocr['level'][i] != Levels.WORD:
            continue
        if not data_ocr['highlighted'][i]:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = (data_ocr['left'][i], data_ocr['top']
                        [i], data_ocr['width'][i], data_ocr['height'][i])
        rect_roi = Rectangle(x, y, x+w, y+h)

        cv2.rectangle(img_result, (rect_roi.xmin, rect_roi.ymin),
                      (rect_roi.xmax, rect_roi.ymax), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return img_result


def draw_text(
    img,
    *,
    text,
    uv_top_left,
    color=(255, 255, 255),
    fontScale=0.5,
    thickness=1,
    fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,
    outline_color=(0, 0, 0),
    line_spacing=1.5,
):
    """
    Draws multiline with an outline.
    https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/596f04c83da9b82d0389d3ea1d782592
    """
    assert isinstance(text, str)

    uv_top_left = np.array(uv_top_left, dtype=float)
    assert uv_top_left.shape == (2,)

    for line in text.splitlines():
        (w, h), _ = cv2.getTextSize(
            text=line,
            fontFace=fontFace,
            fontScale=fontScale,
            thickness=thickness,
        )
        uv_bottom_left_i = uv_top_left + [0, h]
        org = tuple(uv_bottom_left_i.astype(int))

        if outline_color is not None:
            cv2.putText(
                img,
                text=line,
                org=org,
                fontFace=fontFace,
                fontScale=fontScale,
                color=outline_color,
                thickness=thickness * 3,
                lineType=cv2.LINE_AA,
            )
        cv2.putText(
            img,
            text=line,
            org=org,
            fontFace=fontFace,
            fontScale=fontScale,
            color=color,
            thickness=thickness,
            lineType=cv2.LINE_AA,
        )

        uv_top_left += [0, h * line_spacing]

def draw_separation_lines(img_src, images=1):
    height, width = img_src.shape[:2]
    img_result = img_src.copy()

    for i in range(1, images):
        x = int((width / images) * i)
        img_result = cv2.line(img_result, (x, 0), (x, height), (255, 255, 255), thickness=2)

    return img_result

def words_to_string(data_ocr):
    word_list = []
    line_breaks = (Levels.PAGE, Levels.BLOCK, Levels.PARAGRAPH, Levels.LINE)

    for i in range(len(data_ocr['text'])):

        #This is all the information for each word that has been read by OCR
        # print("Level: {}; Page: {}; Block: {}; Paragraph: {}; Line: {}; Word: {}; Highlighted: {} Text: {}".format(
        #     data_ocr['level'][i],
        #     data_ocr['page_num'][i],
        #     data_ocr['block_num'][i],
        #     data_ocr['par_num'][i],
        #     data_ocr['line_num'][i],
        #     data_ocr['word_num'][i],
        #     data_ocr['highlighted'][i],
        #     data_ocr['text'][i]))

        if data_ocr['level'][i] in line_breaks:
            word_list.append("\n")
            continue

        text = data_ocr['text'][i].strip()

        if text and data_ocr['highlighted'][i]:
            word_list.append(text + " ")

    # concat all words into one string
    word_string = "".join(word_list)
    # repalce multiple consecutive newlines with one single newline
    word_string = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', word_string).strip()

    return word_string


def image_to_data(img_src):
    return pytesseract.image_to_data(
        img_src, lang='eng', config='--psm 6', output_type=Output.DICT)


def image_to_string(img_src):
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(
        img_src, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')


def main(args):
    img_input = str(args.img_input)

    # Load image
    img_orig = cv2.imread(img_input)

    # Grayscale and apply Otsu's threshold
    img_thresh, img_gray = threshold_image(img_orig)

    # get ocr data
    data_ocr = image_to_data(img_thresh)

    # yellow highlight colour range
    hsv_lower = [22, 30, 30]
    hsv_upper = [45, 255, 255]

    # Color segmentation
    img_mask, img_hsv = mask_image(
        img_orig, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)

    # Noise reduction
    img_mask_denoised = denoise_image(
        img_mask)

    # Apply mask on original image
    img_orig_masked = apply_mask(img_orig, img_mask=img_mask_denoised)

    # Apply mask on thresholded image
    img_thresh_masked = apply_mask(img_thresh, img_mask=img_mask_denoised)

    data_ocr = find_highlighted_words(
        img_mask_denoised, data_ocr, threshold_percentage=25)

    # Draw contour boundings and bounding boxes
    img_orig_bounding_contour, img_orig_bounding_box = draw_contour_boundings(img_orig, img_mask=img_mask_denoised)

    # Draw word boundings for highlighted words
    img_thresh_word_boundings = draw_word_boundings(img_thresh, data_ocr, highlighted_words=True)
    img_mask_word_boundings = draw_word_boundings(img_mask_denoised, data_ocr, highlighted_words=True)
    img_orig_word_boundings = draw_word_boundings(img_orig, data_ocr, highlighted_words=True)

    # draw all ocr rect
    img_orig_all_ocr = draw_word_boundings(img_orig.copy(), data_ocr)
    img_thresh_all_ocr = draw_word_boundings(img_thresh.copy(), data_ocr)

    img_orig_rects = draw_contour_rectangles(
        img_mask, img_orig.copy())

    img_orig_ocr = mark_highlighted_words(
        img_orig.copy(), data_ocr)


    string_ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        img_thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
        
    #print("\n\n")
    #print(string_ocr)
    #print("\n\n")

    str_highlight = words_to_string(data_ocr)
    print("\n\n")
    print(str_highlight)
    print("\n\n")

    height, width = img_orig.shape[:2]
    img_orig_all_text = np.zeros([height,width,3],dtype=np.uint8)
    img_orig_all_text.fill(255) 
    string_ocr = string_ocr.replace("‘", "'")
    string_ocr = string_ocr.replace("’", "'")
    draw_text(img_orig_all_text, text=string_ocr, color=(0,0,0), outline_color=None, uv_top_left=(100,100), fontScale=1.5,thickness=2)

    img_orig_highlighted_text = np.zeros([height,width,3],dtype=np.uint8)
    img_orig_highlighted_text.fill(255) 
    # string_ocr = string_ocr.replace("‘", "'")
    # string_ocr = string_ocr.replace("’", "'")
    draw_text(img_orig_highlighted_text, text=str_highlight, color=(0,0,0), outline_color=None, uv_top_left=(100,500), fontScale=1.5,thickness=2)


    img_thresholding = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
        (
            img_orig,
            img_gray,
            img_thresh,
        )), axis=1)

    # draw white line between images
    img_thresholding = draw_separation_lines(img_thresholding, images=3)
    cv2.imshow('thresholding', img_thresholding)
    cv2.imwrite("output/thresholding.png", img_thresholding)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    img_extract_all = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
        (
            img_orig_all_ocr,
            img_orig_all_text,
        )), axis=1)

    img_extract_all = draw_separation_lines(img_extract_all, images=2)
    cv2.imshow('extract_all', img_extract_all)
    cv2.imwrite("output/extract_all.png", img_extract_all)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    img_color_segmentation = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
        (
            img_orig,
            img_hsv,
            img_mask,
            
        )), axis=1)

    img_color_segmentation = draw_separation_lines(img_color_segmentation, images=3)
    cv2.imshow('img_color_segmentation', img_color_segmentation)
    cv2.imwrite("output/img_color_segmentation.png", img_color_segmentation)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    img_noise_reduction = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
    (
        img_mask,
        img_mask_denoised
        
    )), axis=1)

    img_noise_reduction = draw_separation_lines(img_noise_reduction, images=2)
    cv2.imshow('img_noise_reduction', img_noise_reduction)
    cv2.imwrite("output/img_noise_reduction.png", img_noise_reduction)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    img_orig_and_mask = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
    (
        img_orig_masked,
        img_thresh_masked
        
    )), axis=1)

    img_orig_and_mask = draw_separation_lines(img_orig_and_mask, images=2)
    cv2.imshow('img_orig_and_mask', img_orig_and_mask)
    cv2.imwrite("output/img_orig_and_mask.png", img_orig_and_mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)    

    img_contour_and_bounding = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
    (
        img_orig_bounding_contour,
        img_orig_bounding_box,
        
    )), axis=1)

    img_contour_and_bounding = draw_separation_lines(img_contour_and_bounding, images=2)
    cv2.imshow('img_contour_and_bounding', img_contour_and_bounding)
    cv2.imwrite("output/img_contour_and_bounding.png", img_contour_and_bounding)
    cv2.waitKey(0)  

    img_final = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
    (
        img_mask_word_boundings,
        img_orig_word_boundings,
        img_orig_highlighted_text
        
    )), axis=1)

    img_final = draw_separation_lines(img_final, images=3)
    cv2.imshow('img_final', img_final)
    cv2.imwrite("output/img_final.png", img_final)
    cv2.waitKey(0)  

    img_title = np.concatenate(normalize_images(
    (
        img_orig,
        img_orig_all_ocr,
        img_orig_bounding_contour,
        img_orig_word_boundings
        
    )), axis=1)

    img_title = draw_separation_lines(img_title, images=4)
    cv2.imshow('img_title', img_title)
    cv2.imwrite("output/img_title.png", img_title)
    cv2.waitKey(0) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    from pathlib import Path

    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('img_input', type=Path, help="Input image")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `Form Recognizer API` returns a different data structure than `PyTesseract`, so you'll need to modify the additional code to work with the new data structure.

Below is sample code snippet that can be used to `extract text` and `bounding box`.

```py
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient

# Replace with your Form Recognizer endpoint and key
endpoint = "https://<Name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
key = "<KEY>"

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(key))

def azure_form_recognizer_ocr(image):
    with open(image, "rb") as image_stream:
        poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content(image_stream)
        result = poller.result()

    words = []
    for page in result:
        for line in page.lines:
            for word in line.words:
                words.append({
                    'text': word.text,
                    'bounding_box': word.bounding_box
                })

    return words
```

Also below is sample code snippet to update the image with bounding box and extracted text:

```py
import cv2
def save_image_with_bounding_boxes(image_path, words, output_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    for word in words:
        bounding_box = word['bounding_box']
        text = word['text']

        # Draw bounding box
        pts = np.array(bounding_box, np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Display text
        x, y = int(bounding_box[0][0]), int(bounding_box[0][1])
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imwrite(output_path, image)
```

With above code snippet I was able to get required results.

```py
image_path =  "sample_invoice.jpg"
words = azure_form_recognizer_ocr(image_path)
save_image_with_bounding_boxes(image_path, words, "sample_invoicev-updated.jpg")
```

[image]
For more details you can check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ai-formrecognizer-readme?view=azure-python)

Comment: I tried using bounding boxes but contour bounding have been working alot better. For example if the highlighted text is from `bounding boxes` to `highlighted text` in this comment. The contour bounding will encapsulate only that much but the bounding box will cover alot of unnecessary words so as to "complete" the rectangle. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.